# Slideup effect on sub menu only works if mouse leaves the div very slowly

Tags: jquery, navigation, padding, slidedown

I have the following script to handle the sliding up and down of a subnavigation menu:

```
$j('body').ready(function() {
    $j('.box').hover(function() {
        $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown(500);
    },
        function() {
            $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp(500);
        });
});
```

The slide down works fine, but the slide up wasn't working at all.  Instead the sub menu was just disappearing suddenly on leaving the .box div.  So I added 4px of padding to the div that contains .box, 4px to the left and right (this is as much as I could spare!).  Now when the mouse leaves the div to the left or right slowly, I do get a slideUp effect, but when doing so at normal speed, still no slide up.  You can see what I mean by visiting [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/), and hovering over the second navigation item ("news").

The padding seems to have helped the detection of the mouse pointer leaving the div, but the slideUp function is still not working well, and surely there's a better solution?  The HTML for the "news" item in the nav list is:

```
<li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
<div class="box">
<div class="top_nav"></div>
<div class="clear">
<div class="bottom_nav"><div class="left_nav"></div><div class="center_nav"><a href="http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/news/">news</a></div><div class="right_nav"></div></a></div></div>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-459" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="top_nav"></div>
    <div class="clear">
    <div class="bottom_nav"><div class="left_nav"></div><div class="center_nav"><a href="http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/news/events/">events</a></div><div class="right_nav"></div></a></div></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually , the main problem is that you have 13 CSS files and 30 javascript files, so you probably have no idea what's going on anymore!

When disabling javascript you will see that you have a hover effect set up in CSS, and another one set up in JS, and they are interfering with each other.

Remove the CSS hover function, and try:

```
$j('.box').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $j('.sub-menu', this).stop(true, true)[e.type==='mouseenter'?'slideDown':'slideUp'](500);
});
```

Notice it's without the `$('body').ready...` stuff, as thats just unnecessary, put it inside a `$(function() {...}) instead.`

Also, there's no need for 30 javascript files, and you don't have to wrap every little function in `$j(function() {...});`, one of those should normally be enough.

There does'nt really seem to be a good reason for running jQuery in noConflict mode either, it looks like it's just a recurring theme to add as much plugins/files/whatnot (read: crap) as humanly possible.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that with javascript disabled the subnavigation still works, but without the drop-down/fade in jQuery effects.  It looks like the CSS that is controlling the hover effect is in the default CSS for the Wordpress theme I am using.  I am using a child theme to override the default CSS.  The number of CSS and javascript files are largely due to it being a Wordpress environment.  Can you see which CSS I need to change to disable the hover effect?  I  have tried disabling various CSS using Web Inspector for divs such as #nav li:hover, but this hasn't worked out.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that jQuery is broken right now on the site due to conflict with a WP plugin, and I'm leaving it that way so that the developer of this plugin can take a look.  In terms of the issue in question here, hopefully this is effectively the same as disabling the JS, so it shouldn't make any difference to sorting out the CSS.

Comment: I have marked your answer as the correct answer as I think you are right, but I'm still not sure how to remove the CSS hover function, so if you have any more advice about this I'd be glad to hear of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you're not clearing the jQuery animation queue.

Also, you should store `$j(this).find('.sub-menu')` in a global variable.

Here's the code:

```
var subMenu; /* Global variable */

$j('body').ready(function() {
    $j('.box').hover(function() {
        if(subMenu == null)
        {
            subMenu = $j(this).find('.sub-menu');
        }
        subMenu.stop(); /* Clears animation before applying slideDown */
        subMenu.slideDown(500);
    },
        function() {
            if(subMenu == null)
            {
                subMenu = $j(this).find('.sub-menu');
            }
            subMenu.stop(); /* clears animation before applying slideUp */
            /* you might need to put a 'subMenu.show();' here in case it's not visible */
            subMenu.slideUp(500);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added your function and still don't see proper sliding up of the submenu, as you can see [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/).  I have tried with and without `subMenu.show();`

Comment: @Nick There may be a conflict with the green hover effect, try disabling it. Also, try leaving subMenu.show();

Comment: I have disabled the green hover effect and included `subMenu.show();` as you suggest, but I still see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the element for event. Probably element has more event to deal with.